# Rename subfolder: add leading word from parent folder

Tags: shell, directory, rename, subdirectory, total-commander

I have a large music library organized in `Artist` folders with `Album` subfolders:

```
Artist 1
- Album A
-- File 1
-- File 2
- Album B
-- File 1
-- File 2
Artist 2
- Album C
-- File 1
-- File 2
- Album D
-- File 1
-- File 2
```

Now I want to rename all `Album` folders by adding the `Artist` name as prefix AND move all `Album` folders in to the **root** directory, like this:

```
Artist 1 - Album A
- File 1
- File 2
Artist 1 - Album B
- File 1
- File 2
Artist 2 - Album C
- File 1
- File 2
Artist 2 - Album D
- File 1
- File 2
```

What is the best way to do that? I tried to do it with Total Commander, but I don't get it. Or maybe shell, mp3tag? I use Windows 10.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok guys, I found an ANSWER by myself. Best way to do it is to use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/) tool. You can create new folders and copy your files in it. 

1. select `Converter > Tag - Filename`
2. type in: `E:\%artist% - %album%\$num(%track%,2) - %title%`

You'll receive a directory with `Artist - Albumname\01 - File.mp3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself. The best way to do it is to use mp3tag tool. You can create new folders and copy your files in it.

1. Select Converter > Tag - Filename
2. Type in:

   ```
   E:\%artist% - %album%\$num(%track%,2) - %title%
   ```

You'll receive a directory with Artist - Albumname\01 - File.mp3

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in several ways, actually. I'll show how in `bash`, but that's only if you have that thing of *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows*. Again:

### BASH

Assuming that your music library is `~/Music/`, that all the artist folders are inside, that you accept to have everything moved to a new folder, assuming that it doesn't yet exist (because if you had an artist folder named 'CoolSinger' and just *accidentally* you also have another artist folder named 'CoolSinger - CoolAlbum', by a mistake, there would be problems...), and that there are not any other files involved than what you state, the shell script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ~/NewMusic/
for artistdir in ~/Music/*; do
  artistname="$(basename "${artistdir}")"
  for albumdir in "${artistdir}"/*; do
    albumname="$(basename "${albumdir}")"
    mv "${albumdir}" ~/NewMusic/"${artistname} - ${albumname}" 2>/dev/null
  done
done
```

And let me explain it in human:

Create the destination folder. Then, for every `artist` (assuming all are folders); iterate through every `album` sub-folder, moving it to the new folder, and renaming it, by the way, using the artist name and folder name from the actual folder names. If everything went OK, this would result in:

- A folder `~/Music/` with the original sub-folder names, but they're now empty.
- A folder `~/NewMusic` with the desired structure.
- If an artist folder is empty, the shell would try to throw an error because it expands to the literal string (explained later), but don't worry, because if it is empty, then anything is to do with it, so you can ignore it, appending `2>/dev/null` to the command. However, if anything else goes wrong with this, it will also be silenced.

If you wanted to, let's say, stay with the original files, `and` have a copy of all that with the desired structure, you should change the `mv` command for a `cp -R` one.

And all that is for a script, in a file. If you wanted to execute it right from the command line, which would make somewhat tricky to change the folder name for the music library, it would look like this:

```
mkdir ~/NewMusic/; for artistdir in ~/Music/*; do artistname="$(basename "${artistdir}")"; for albumdir in "${artistdir}"/*; do albumname="$(basename "${albumdir}")"; mv "${albumdir}" ~/NewMusic/"${artistname} - ${albumname}"; done; done
```

And an explanation of everything there:

1. `mkdir` creates the directory.
2. `for A in B ; do C ; done` is a loop. It loops through every string separated by one of the IFS characters in `B`, and assign it as a value for the variable `A`, while it executes `C`.

   - Note that the text in the script has an asterisk. The shell expands a string with an asterisk to what it finds to match the pattern. For instance, if you had a bunch of Word documents, typing `echo *.docx` would expand to every name matching that ending, in the current folder (in another case, `echo /path/*.docx`).
3. So, for every folder inside the specified directory, assign (once for every artist folder) the variable `artistname` with the base name of the file specified (in this case, the folder) as its value. So, `basename /path/to/anything` returns `anything`.
4. With the help of another `for` loop, do for every element inside the artist directory, rename it as specified, and if the new name is in another directory, it will move it there.

   - Again, the `2>/dev/null` redirection is there to redirect all output in `stderr` to the void. Output in `stdout` would be still printed, though, if there was any.

### SOME IMPORTANT NOTES

- I don't have any idea whether the shell from *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows* detects `/dev/null` as the special character file that a standard UNIX machine has or not. *Likely* it does, or it wouldn't be compatible with so many things.
- This is **only** if you have *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows* in your Windows 10. If I recall correctly, the chance of using it was implemented with the Anniversary Update. If you have the update, but not `bash`, I recommend you to install it. There are several guides over that on the Internet.
- About the folder structure. I suspect the same about `/dev/null` as for the POSIX folder structure: that it follows it, as it's not just *Bash on Windows*, but *Bash on **Ubuntu** on Windows*.

Comment: thank you for you extended answer. since i'm not on linux and have no experience with bash, I would surely need time to test that way... maybe it will work, I'll see. thanks again.